# Print value is not working as required

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

I am trying to **print** a dynamic value into the query, according to the condition which I am passing as a **parameter**, but it is not printing.

Below is the query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Leave_Allocate_CuttOff]
    @Type nvarchar(10),
    @Month int,
    @Year int
 AS 
BEGIN
declare @actualMonth int
declare @actualYear int
declare @actuallastdate varchar(20)
declare @DAMonth int
declare @DAYear int
Declare @Final_LOP as numeric(5,2) 
Declare @Final_LOPDays as numeric(5,2) 
declare @checkRecord int
declare @NoOfDaysForDelayApproval numeric(5,2)
declare @Leave_Default numeric(5,2) 
declare @status varchar(10)
declare @resig_date datetime
declare @dt_of_leave datetime
declare @emp_name varchar(20)
declare @dt_of_join datetime
declare @emp_card_no numeric(9)
declare @pl_days numeric(5,2)
declare @pl_days_opening numeric(5,2)
declare @Month_Diff int
declare @month1 numeric(5,2)
declare @month2 numeric(5,2)
declare @month3 numeric(5,2)
declare @month4 numeric(5,2)
declare @month5 numeric(5,2)
declare @month6 numeric(5,2)
declare @month7 numeric(5,2)
declare @month8 numeric(5,2)
declare @month9 numeric(5,2)
declare @month10 numeric(5,2)
declare @month11 numeric(5,2)
declare @month12 numeric(5,2)
declare @pl_sum numeric(5,2)
declare @Total_days numeric(5,2)
declare @Days_worked numeric(5,2)
declare @actualleavedays numeric(5,2) 
declare @Final_PaidDayLop numeric(5,2)
declare @Opg_bal numeric(5,2)
declare @remaingPL as numeric(5,2)   
declare @DelayedMonth int
declare @DelayedYear int
declare @LOP_value  as numeric(5,2)  
declare @emp_type  varchar(2)
declare @emp_mkey int 
declare @PL_Opening_2015 numeric(10,2)
declare @TOTAL_PL_Allocation_2015 numeric(10,2)
declare @PL_Alloc_2015_Month1 numeric(10,2)
declare @PL_Alloc_2015_Month2 numeric(10,2)
declare @PL_Alloc_2015_Month3 numeric(10,2)
declare @PL_Alloc_2015_Month4 numeric(10,2)
declare @PL_Alloc_2015_Month5 numeric(10,2)
declare @PL_Alloc_2015_Month6 numeric(10,2)
declare @PL_Alloc_2015_Month7 numeric(10,2)
declare @PL_Alloc_2015_Month8 numeric(10,2)
declare @PL_Alloc_2015_Month9 numeric(10,2)
declare @PL_Alloc_2015_Month10 numeric(10,2)
declare @PL_Alloc_2015_Month11 numeric(10,2)
declare @PL_Alloc_2015_Month12 numeric(10,2)
declare @TOTAL_OL_Alloc_2015 numeric(10,2)
declare @OL_Alloc_2015_MONTH1 numeric(10,2)
declare @OL_Alloc_2015_MONTH2 numeric(10,2)
declare @OL_Alloc_2015_MONTH3 numeric(10,2)
declare @OL_Alloc_2015_MONTH4 numeric(10,2)
declare @OL_Alloc_2015_MONTH5 numeric(10,2)
declare @OL_Alloc_2015_MONTH6 numeric(10,2)
declare @OL_Alloc_2015_MONTH7 numeric(10,2)
declare @OL_Alloc_2015_MONTH8 numeric(10,2)
declare @OL_Alloc_2015_MONTH9 numeric(10,2)
declare @OL_Alloc_2015_MONTH10 numeric(10,2)
declare @OL_Alloc_2015_MONTH11 numeric(10,2)
declare @OL_Alloc_2015_MONTH12 numeric(10,2)
declare @Mkey int
declare @Entry_Sr_no int
declare @dcount int
declare @EmpnameCalculation  varchar(75)
set @Leave_Default=1.75
IF (@Month = 1)
    BEGIN
        set  @actualYear = @Year - 1
        set  @actualMonth = 12
        set  @DelayedMonth = 11
        set  @DelayedYear = @Year - 1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        set @actualYear = @Year
        set @actualMonth = @Month - 1

        IF (@Month = 2)
            BEGIN
                set @DelayedMonth = 12
                set  @DelayedYear = @Year - 1
            END
        Else
            BEGIN
                set @DelayedMonth = @actualMonth - 1
                set @DelayedYear = @Year 
            END
    END
Print 'Actual Year ' + cast(@actualYear as VARCHAR)
Print 'Actual Month ' + Cast(@actualMonth as varchar)
Print 'Delayed Year ' + Cast(@DelayedYear as varchar)
Print 'Delayed Month' + Cast(@DelayedMonth  as varchar)
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME;
    SET @DATE = CAST(CAST(@actualYear AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST(@DelayedMonth AS VARCHAR)+'-'+ Cast(Day(DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(month,@DelayedMonth,DATEADD(year,@actualYear-1900,0)))) AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME);
PRINT Convert(varchar(11),@DATE,103)
set @actuallastDate = convert(varchar(10),'1/'+Convert(Varchar,@actualMonth)+'/'+Convert(Varchar,@actualYear),103)
print @actuallastDate
IF(@Type = 'M')
        BEGIN
            Print 'Yes I am in the Monthly process'
            SELECT @checkRecord = COUNT(Year) FROM p_leave_allocation  where Year = @Year

                IF(@checkRecord = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        Print 'Kindly Run Annual process first for creation of Blank Records for New Year.'
                        RETURN 
                    END 
                        declare monthly_Allocate cursor  for
                        Select e.status,e.resig_date, dt_of_leave, e.emp_name,e.date_of_joining,  e.emp_card_no,
                                a.pl_days,pl_days_opening,
                                a.month1,a.month2,a.month3,a.month4,a.month5,a.month6,a.month7,a.month8,a.month9,a.month10,a.month11,a.month12,--actual_pl,
                                a.month1+a.month2+a.month3+a.month4+a.month5+a.month6+a.month7+a.month8+a.month9++a.month10+a.month11+a.month12 pl_sum
                        from p_leave_allocation a join emp_mst e on a.emp_card_no=e.emp_card_no 
                        where a.year=@actualYear
                                and (datediff(month,e.date_of_joining,convert(datetime,@actuallastDate,103)) >= 6 
                             and datediff(month,e.date_of_joining,convert(datetime,@actuallastDate,103)) <= 36)
                            and (e.resig_date is null or  (e.dt_of_leave is not null  and e.dt_of_leave >= convert(datetime,@actuallastDate,103)))
                            and e.status in ('A','S')
                            and e.comp_mkey in (Select  distinct m.comp_mkey from emp_mst e, company_mst c, P_Monthly_Must_Para_Hdr m where c.mkey = e.comp_mkey 
                            and m.comp_mkey  = e.comp_mkey and (m.process_date is not null 
                            and  (convert(varchar,(getDate())-4,103)) = convert(varchar,m.process_date, 103)))
                        order by 7,5 

                        PRINT 'Employee Calculation' -- + @EmpnameCalculation  // It is not getting printed

                        OPEN monthly_Allocate fetch next
                            FROM monthly_Allocate into 
                            @status,@resig_date,@dt_of_leave,@emp_name, @dt_of_join,@emp_card_no,@pl_days,@pl_days_opening,
                            @month1,@month2,@month3,@month4,@month5,@month6,@month7,@month8,@month9,@month10,@month11,@month12,@pl_sum
                        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    BEGIN
                            set @actualleavedays = 0
                            set @Final_PaidDayLop = 0

                            Print 'Faiz K.' + cast(@emp_card_no as varchar(10))

                            select  @Total_days =  Sum(total_day), @Days_worked = Sum(days_worked)       
                            from    emp_mon_day a      
                            where   a.emp_mkey =  @emp_card_no
                                    and a.month = @actualMonth and Year = @actualYear
                            group by emp_mkey       

                            print @emp_card_no
                            print @Total_days
                            print @Days_worked

                            if(@Days_worked > 0)
                                BEGIN
                                    --set @actualleavedays =((1.75) / @Total_days) * (@Days_worked)
                                    Set @actualleavedays = (cast(@Leave_Default as numeric(18,2))/cast(@Total_days as numeric(18,2)))* cast(@Days_worked as numeric(18,2))                                          
                                END 

                            print @actualleavedays  

                            DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

                            PRINT @sql 
                            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;

                            BEGIN   
                                    declare @totaldaysofmonth decimal(9,2)
                                    set @totaldaysofmonth =  DAY(DATEADD(ms,-2,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@DATE)+1,0)))

                                    select @NoOfDaysForDelayApproval=isnull(sum(Total_Days),0.00) 
                                    from XXACL_EMP_DELAY_APPROVAL_V  
                                    where DYear = @DelayedYear  and DMonth = @DelayedMonth
                                            and CardNo = @emp_card_no

                                    print   @NoOfDaysForDelayApproval

                                    declare @DelayleaveAllocate decimal(9,2)                                
                                    set     @DelayleaveAllocate = ((1.75 / @totaldaysofmonth) * @NoOfDaysForDelayApproval)                                          

                                    print   @DelayleaveAllocate

                                    SET @sql = '';
                                    print 'Yes 01'
                                    print @DelayedMonth

                                    declare @strmon varchar(100) 
                                    set @strmon= 'cast(month'+ CAST(@DelayedMonth AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' as numeric(10,2)) + cast(' + cast(@DelayleaveAllocate as varchar(50)) +' as numeric(10,2))'


                                    print   @DelayleaveAllocate
                            END   
                            FETCH NEXT
                            FROM monthly_Allocate into 
                            @status,@resig_date,@dt_of_leave,@emp_name, @dt_of_join,@emp_card_no,@pl_days,@pl_days_opening,
                            @month1,@month2,@month3,@month4,@month5,@month6,@month7,@month8,@month9,@month10,@month11,@month12,@pl_sum
                END
                close monthly_Allocate
                deallocate  monthly_Allocate            
            END
END
```

and while executing I am running like this

```
-- exec Leave_Allocate_CuttOff M, 2, 2016
```

But the value for `EmpnameCalculation` is not getting printed.

I don't know what is the cause.

I am using **SQL server 2008**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing comments,which you have like below

--this doesnt work

```
declare @a int
set @a=3
print '@a value'-----+@a
```

--this works

```
declare @a int
set @a=3
print '@a value'+cast(@a as char)
```

Comment: yeah, it worked. but there were 9 names and it is just showing me 1

Comment: You have to debug your code step by step by using same print statements  and see where you are populating those values\

Comment: i guess, I need to run a cursor for that too.. what say ?

Comment: You might have to see your code  to see if those check conditions are passed,i am not sure